# Header 1 between 2 images

Tags: html, css, header

I need to make an H1 with images on both sides.

It needs to be on one line and has to be responsive.

Like this, but the ==== is an image of an small line:

=========HEADER TEXT============

Current code is:

```
<h1><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/mintbar.png"}}" alt="" /> of WATCHES &amp; MEN <img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/mintbar.png"}}" alt="" /></h1>
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you heard of CSS? that is how you will accomplish your goal http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp

Comment: Yes, but what CSS code comes with what i need to accomplish?

Comment: It's quite easy to do this, but there are various considerations. Will the line cover the whole page, or just the content area?

Comment: Are image tags inside h1 tags a good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the images and the h1 title set as inline-blocks: http://jsfiddle.net/

HTML:

```
<img id="image-surround" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/mintbar.png"}}" alt="" />
<h1>of WATCHES &amp; MEN</h1> 
<img id="image-surround" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/mintbar.png"}}" alt="" />
```

CSS:

```
#image-surround { display: inline-block;
}

h1 { display: inline-block;
}
```

---

Of course, you'll need to have a container for it all to have it properly responsive. 
http://jsfiddle.net/qn8dnvmg/4/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="columns onethird">
        <img id="image-surround" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/mintbar.png"}}" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="columns onethird">
        <h1>of WATCHES &amp; MEN</h1> 
    </div>
    <div class="columns onethird">
        <img id="image-surround" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/mintbar.png"}}" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container { position: relative; 
margin: 0 auto; 
padding: 0; 
width: 960px;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
}

.container .column, .container .columns { float: left; 
display: inline; 
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
padding-left: 2px;
padding-right: 2px;
}

.row { margin-bottom: 20px; 
}

.clear { clear: both;
height: 1px;
width: 100%;
}

.container .onehalf.columns { width: 50%; }
.container .full.columns { width: 100%; }

.container .onethird.columns { width: 33.33%; }
.container .twothirds.columns { width: 66.66%; }

.container .onequarter.columns { width: 25%; }
.container .twoquarters.columns { width: 50%; }
.container .threequarters.columns { width: 75%; }

.container .onefifth.columns { width: 20%; }
.container .twofifths.columns { width: 40%; }
.container .threefifths.columns { width: 60%; }
.container .fourfifths.columns { width: 80%; }

.container .oneeight.columns { width: 12.5%; }
.container .twoeights.columns { width: 25%; }
.container .threeeights.columns { width: 37.5%; }
.container .foureights.columns { width: 50%; }
.container .fiveeights.columns { width: 62.5%; }
.container .sixeights.columns { width: 75%; }
.container .seventeights.columns { width: 87.5%; }

.container .onetenth.columns { width: 10%; }
.container .twotenths.columns { width: 20%; }
.container .threetenths.columns { width: 30%; }
.container .fourtenths.columns { width: 40%; }
.container .fivetenths.columns { width: 50%; }
.container .sixtenths.columns { width: 60%; }
.container .seventhtenths.columns { width: 70%; }
.container .eighttenths.columns { width: 80%; }
.container .ninetenths.columns { width: 90%; }
```

And then your media queries etc.

Comment: Thanks! The columns are working properly, but when I enter a longer title it goes on the next line.

Comment: Well, there's only so much you can do to fit it all on one line. I mean, I don't think you can place a paragraph and believe it'll all go on a single line (unless your increase the width of your container). I can only suggest making the container bigger, the font smaller, or the sentence shorter. Of course, let me know if you meant something else.